# how to reference linq in user control?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sharepoint, user-controls

I'm trying to use `linq` in a `user control`, but I get this error with the reference `"System.Linq"`.

> Error:"c:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES\MyUserControl.ascx.cs(23): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

Comment: add using System.Linq; on top.

Comment: I have the line, I'm getting the exception in that line :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your `.Net` Framework version. [System.Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.aspx) is supported by .Net Framework 3.5 and above.

and then simply write using statement to include namespace

```
using System.Linq;
```

you can check the Framework version under Properties option of your project

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a repeat of other answers but this is what you have?
As per the other answer (that you should mark as the answer).
LINQ was not around until version 3.5.
It could be you have 3.5 installed on the computer but your project is pointed to an older version.
Under References check the version of System.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Linq;

namespace LotsOfUpDownKeys
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for UserControl1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, this is typically assumed but check the references in your project (references folder).  You should have a reference to System.Core